# Android: How can I start a timer that begins at the next exact multiple of 2 seconds?

Tags: java, android, timer, android-service

I am new to android and have been thrown in at the deep end with a somewhat complicated project.

I effectively have a number of devices running the same app and they are either staff or Exclusion zones.
I need to use bluetooth beacons to have the devices transmit their GPS coordinates, and the exclusion zones also transmit their boundary size (Bluetooth beacon distance detection was not reliably accurate enough.)

What I want to do is have a service running (I think) that has the staff devices listen for one second, whilst the exclusion zones broadcast, then all devices flip between listening and broadcasting for the next second, then repeat.
Any detected boundary violations calculated by taking the distance between the devices own GPS coordinate and any that have been broadcast by other devices of the opposing type are then to be logged.

How can I get a timer to start, and repeatedly call the function every 2 seconds, at the next exact multiple of 2 seconds?

- NOT 2 seconds from the point at which the function is called. For instance if the time is 12h:35m:01s:223ms I want the repeating function to be called at 12:35:02

Answer (score 1):

Compute the time remaining to the next two-second mark and then use that to schedule a delayed, one-time task that will start a two-second repeating timer.

Comment: Thought this may be the case. Was wondering if android had anything a little bit more precise

Comment: In response to my previous comment I come from an embedded micro background so was expecting far more delay when performing each operation. Didn't realise that it would take under a ms to execute said calculations! XD

Comment: @GigaJoules - Yeah, there will be a slight uncertainty about the timing, but if you can tolerate a 1 ms out-of-sync condition, then this simple approach will do fine. One ms is a huge amount of time on most modern Java platforms. If you need better synchronization, you'll probably have to implement some sort of sync protocol (like, say, Network Time Protocol) to adjust for computation and communication delays. That can probably get your processors within a few microseconds of one another.

Comment: had my thread spit out system time in ms & noticed that there was some drift, increasing by about 1ms per cycle. 
Cleaned up nicely by using the same trick of shaving off the excess ms from when the next cycle is scheduled. 
Now only drifts by up to 3ms. 
On the other hand I've realised I'm an idiot and there is no garauntee that the system times are going to be accurate enough to pull off what I'm trying to do. Will have to try and sync the devices using timestamps in the bluetooth packets or something
Unfortunately part of the spec is that there is no garauntee of network connection